# Unsupported version of the Android Gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to migrate eclipse project to android studio,But I am getting following error,

**Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 2.1.2.
Fix plugin version and sync project**

This question is asked in stackoverflow,I tried to suggestion given but its not working for me.Any help greatly appreciated.

Below is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Below is my gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
#Mon Jun 20 13:18:24 IST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

**Update:-**

After adding `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'` to ROOT/build.gradle I am getting following error.

```
Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'UberTest' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Fix plugin version and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'UberTest' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Comment: you have update you android studio to 2.1

Comment: please add your TOP level build.gradle..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya I have paste entire build.gradle.There is nothing on top.

Comment: I m saying about your **TOP LEVEL** builg.gradle..!! this will be outside your app module..!! there will be another build.gradle.. Other then this..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya both gradle are identical,I checked it.

Comment: not possible the two can not be identical..!!

Comment: Ya your right but I dont know but when migrating from eclipse to android studio both gradle look identical.

Comment: Click `Fix plugin version and sync project` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Gabriele and @ldkxingzhe for your suggestions and answers,Unfortunately that did not fix my problem.

What I did was instead of exporting eclipse android project I just imported project directly to android studio,As mentioned below link,in section **Import Directly into Android Studio**

[http://www.developer.com/ws/android/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio.html]

This has fixed my build.gradle error and Working as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The version of your gradle is too old. like janki gadhiya said, In your TOP level build.gradle(The TOP level build.gradle is your root directory, there is also a file named settings.gradle), change the version of gradle to 2.1.2:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

then sync your gradle, something will be fine.

**another way** is reopen your project, the Android studio should hint you to update your gradle, and then click fix.

Comment: There is no settings.gradle in my project.

Comment: where is your gradle-wrapper.properties? It's root is ROOT/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties. and your TOP LEVEL build.gradle path is ROOT/build.gradle.

Comment: your project should [like this picture](http://static.open-open.com/lib/uploadImg/20150708/20150708104746_354.png)

Comment: gradle-wrapper.properties is in ROOT/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties.

Comment: The TOP level build gradle is : ROOT/build.gradle

Comment: Added classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'  to ROOT/build.gradle but still no luck,I am getting different error.I update my question with error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest stable versions of the gradle and gradle plugin (Don't confuse them).

In your `root/build.gradle` use: (**gradle-plugin for android**)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

In the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file use: (**gradle**)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Also go to  **File > Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle** 
and set **Use default gradle wrapper**

[image]

Comment: I tried what you suggested,But I got following error,     Error:Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a>

Comment: Go to  File > Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle -> and set "Use default gradle wrapper"